# Error during CSSCAN of Oracle11 database

Tags: oracle, character-set

I have an issue when trying to change the character set on an Oracle 11.2 database.

Here are the particulars:

- Oracle 11.2 64 bit, running under Oracle Linux 7
- This is a new installation (i.e. the only users are those that were created during the Oracle install), using the defaults given during the Oracle installation
- The current NLS_CHARACTERSET is AL32UTF8, and I need to
  convert it to either WE8MSWIN1252 or WE8DEC

Most of my experience with Oracle has been with Windows, and I've never had to change the character sets before.

Now I can't just change the character set from AL32UTF8 to WE8DEC or WE8MSWIN1252 because those aren't supersets. So, I ran CSINST.SQL, and ran the CSSCAN command. Most of the scan was successful, but I ended up receiving the following errors:

> . processs 1 scanning XDB.PRIN_PT[AAAN9DAACAAAEGoAAA]
>   ORA-30967: operation directly on the Path Table is disallowed
>   CSS-00144: failed to scan table XDB.PRIN_PT

Does anyone have any idea what the problem can be and/or how to fix it?

I've done some searching.I did find someone who has mentioned deleting and recreating XML indexes, but I've never done that.

Comment: If this is a new installation, is there a reason that you don't just re-install with the character set that you want?  That's generally going to be easier than trying to do a conversion.  Functionally, I'm not sure why you'd want to convert away from a Unicode character set but I assume you have your reasons.

Comment: Got to agree with @JustinCave on this one...

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue for Oracle Database version 11.2 or higher where [XDB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb01int.htm) is installed. My Oracle Support says this can be ignored and has been fixed in 11.2.0.2

Installing and configuring Csscan in 10g and 11g (Database Character Set Scanner) (Doc ID 745809.1)